# Reading signifnance of regression in lead/lag regressions

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I'm running a couple of fixed effect regressions with the leads of my independent variable. My outcome variable is the number of people absent in a set of factories (unit) and my independent variable is the cumulative number of employees who attended the health camps conducted in those factories. I created three leads of this variable (for time unit 't' which is 'weeks') in anticipating possible pre trends. So the leads would include, the cum frequency 3 previous weeks of camps.

My question is, in the regression results I have attached how do i interpret the lead variables being significant but when running a regression together, the coefficients are not significant?

[image]

Comment: What is the time unit here? Does 1 correspond to t-1 and so on?

Comment: I have edited my post for more detail! So time unit is weeks, 't'. So the three leads are essentially; 1 week in advance, 2 weeks in advance and 3 weeks in advance. The number  above the variable to different models (which are different in terms of the FE considered , indicated at the bottom, and the variables included)